# Check if container of shared_ptr contains a pointer?

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, shared-ptr

Using Observer pattern.  I have a class, called Monitor for example, that is monitoring a collection of objects.  The class is an Observer and each object in it's collection is a Subject.  Currently the collection is implemented as a std::list of shared_ptr.  In the Update method of the Monitor class I want to check if the update is coming from one of the objects in it's collection.

```
std::list<SomeSharedPointer> items_;
...
void Monitor::Update(Subject *subject)
{
    if(subject == something_)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else if
    ??
    // if subject is one of the objects in our collection then do something..

}
```

Subject here is a raw pointer and my collection is a list of shared_ptr.  How can I effectively check if the subject coming in is any one of the objects in my collection?

(Note my compiler, msvc, supports lambdas if there is an algorithmic solution requiring one)

**UPDATE**

I should add that I realize I can use a for loop over the container, but I'm wondering if there's a snazzier way.

**UPDATE 2**

`SomeSharedPointer` is a typedef for `std::shared_ptr<SomeType>` where `SomeType` derives from abstract class `Subject` (standard Observer pattern implementation).  SomeType will at some point call `Notify()` which will call the `Update()` method for each observer.

Comment: Sounds like a broken design. Normal observers do not have to make that check. On long runs, you are better with adding special observer for that type

Comment: It's possible. It's a manager class that needs to make decisions based on the state of items it's monitoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
auto i = std::find_if(items_.begin(), items_.end(), 
    [=](const SomeSharedPointer& x) { return x.get() == subject; });

if (i != c.end())
{ 
    // Object found, and i is an iterator pointing to it
}
```

A little helper method can make this more readable:

```
typedef std::list<SomeSharedPtr> ObserverCollection;

// You can also add a const version if needed
ObserverCollection::iterator find_observer(Subject* s)
{
    return std::find_if(items_.begin(), items_.end(), 
        [=](const SomeSharedPointer& x) { return x.get() == s; });
}
```

Then, you use it like this if you need the iterator

```
auto i = find_observer(subject);
if (i != items_.end())
{
    // Object found
}
```

or simply like this if you don't:

```
if (find_observer(subject) != items_.end())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: wait what happened to the boolean helper method you had?

Comment: @User: It depends on what you want to do. Let me edit the post to get it back. Indeed, if you want to manipulate the object, you need an iterator to it.

Comment: Also what does the `=` mean in `[=]` in the lambda expression?

Comment: `[=]` means capture variables referenced outside the scope of the lambda by value.

Comment: @User: The `[=]` is here to capture the `subject` pointer inside the lambda. We capture it by value (we could have captured it by reference with `[&]`).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have C++11 support for auto, declare the iterator the old fashioned way

```
for (auto iter = items_.begin(); iter != items_.end(); ++iter)
{
     if (subject == iter->get())
     {
         .. do stuff ..
     }
}
```

Shared pointer has a .get() function that returns the pointer.

Comment: it's a collection though, not single instance.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were already iterating over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that the observer needs to make a decision based on a state of items it is monitoring, then you should add a method to the base class (`Subject` in your question) which returns an enum defining the item's state. Then based on the state, add a switch in the update method:

```
enum State{ STATE_1, STATE_2 };

void Monitor::Update(Subject *subject)
{
    switch( subject->getState() )
    {
      case STATE_1:
         // do something 1
         break;
      case STATE_2:
         // do something 2
         break;
      default:
         //error
    }
}
```

Comment: it needs to make decisions based on the *aggregate* state rather than the state of any one item.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, you could consider changing your container to something that gives you better search behavior. For instance, you could use a `std::set`. It costs more per insertion, but faster per lookup. Or, `std::unordered_set`. Both insertion and lookup are fast, but iteration is likely slower. To achieve proper comparison, you can create a helper class to enable converting your raw pointer into a shared pointer that has an no-op deleter.

```
template <typename T>
struct unshared_ptr {
    std::shared_ptr<T> p_;
    unshared_ptr (T *p) : p_(p, [](...){}) {}
    operator const std::shared_ptr<T> & () const { return p_; }
    operator T * () const { return p_.get(); }
};
```

If your container supported the `find` method, then:

```
typedef unshared_ptr<SomeType> unshared_some;
if (items_.end() != items_.find(unshared_some(subject))) {
    DoSomething();
}
```

<sub>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBLboMwEN1ziimVKrtqOUBCWPcA7NoqsmAglvBH9lhVhHJ2akLCp413837jN5W1721VDc9SV12oEXKFyrhzkSyIR1qPomuNk3RSGw05qds1Ik3EUKhiIFS2ExQxOlvUQiGURRLZUBEE7U/CYX205KBPID5P9W63oHlZgD3ur9RGzUp4tRx2kWX2DT6/WZZlvL9w6C9XtbHoBBkHldGeHuW@AOM3tgeHFJwed8Eff1z0UJi1SIyP8ss@SaQmUELqUTo1GfvW2PzbPM3TyeCGx3G/Ma27bh0zM3smGilfiBhM7hixSSECGfBwAI0/sEpj6Qd2nUn5PejqyaT26Igtcczzm0Q2wO4y1HUs@3SYfY2MyPp/o@9@jvmnlQkEeQ5pY4Kuv3Q6JcczDsMv)</sub>

If you are sticking with `std::list`, you can abuse the `remove_if` method by passing in a predicate that always returns false, but performs your matching test.

```
bool matched = false;
auto pred = [subject, &matched](SomeSharedPtr &v) -> bool {
    if (!matched && v.get() == subject) {
        matched = true;
    }
    return false;
};
items_.remove_if(pred);
if (matched) {
    DoSomething();
} //...
```

Comment: Yuk! Where do you get those ideas?

Comment: @curiousguy: I abuse APIs for a living.